# ruby gems on xampp help

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i have googled in the last 3 hours but i can't seem to find any precise info. All i know is PHP, i don't know anything about ruby or ror, I need to run this open source project management app http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineInstall on my xampp, but can anyone tell me how to do things properly i mean install stuff with my xampp ? (please) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running Ruby on Rails applications on Xampp you have multiple choices.
The one which I prefer is using [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/)

Installation is easy and it has really good performance.
Documentation is great aswell and it is all on the posted site.

Comment: sir i have installed the ruby, rails and rake successfully, but the problem now is how am i gonna run this web application ?, i don't see any "install" stuff, unlike in PHP :( http://i49.tinypic.com/259coys.jpg

Comment: Please look into the link to Phusion Passenger I posted for how to run the rails application on your apache server.